# Почему в laravel в файле .gitignore есть public/build если при деплое сайт требует оттуда файлы, а запустить npm run build на хостинге не получается

Tags: php, laravel, tailwindcss

[image: Вот ошибка]

запустить npm install,npm run build и тд не получается потому что не находит команду npm

Comment: Эта папка нужна для собранных (скомпилированных) файлов, которые отдаются сервером для работы страниц, и их не стоит хранить в репозитории. Читайте документацию вашего хостинг-провайдера, либо связывайтесь с их поддержкой для решения вопроса сборки.